# How to list subfolders in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to write a script which cleans up old builds in my generic file repository in Artifactory. I guess the first step would be to look in the repository and check which builds are in there.

Each build shows up as a subfolder of `/foo`, so for example I have folders `/foo/123`, `/foo/124`, `/foo/125`/, etc.

There doesn't seem to be a `ls` or `dir` command. So I tried the `search` command:

```
jfrog rt search my-repo/foo/*
```

But this recursively lists all files, which is not what I'm looking for. I just need the list of direct subfolders. I also tried

```
jfrog rt search my-repo/foo/* --recursive=false
```

but this doesn't return any results, because the search command only returns files, not folders.

How do I list the subfolders of a given folder in an Artifactory repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jfrog cli now includes the `--include-dirs` option for search.

The command:

```
jf rt search --recursive=false --include-dirs path/
```

will essentially act like an `ls`.

Answer (score 10):

Just one more way to do it with curl and jq

```
curl -s http://myatifactory.domain:4567/artifactory/api/storage/myRepo/myFolder | jq -r '.children[] |select(.folder==true) |.uri'
```

Explanation: [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is used to [get the folder info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FolderInfo) and that is piped to [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) which then displays all the `uri` keys of the `children` array whose `folder` key has value `true`.

Just for easier understanding -  the json that curl gets looks something like this (example from artifactory docs)

```
{
"uri": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme",
"repo": "libs-release-local",
"path": "/org/acme",
"created": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
"createdBy": "userY",
"lastModified": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
"modifiedBy": "userX",
"lastUpdated": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
"children": [
{
            "uri" : "/child1",
            "folder" : "true"
        },{
            "uri" : "/child2",
            "folder" : "false"
         }
]
}
```

and for it the output of the command would be `/child1`.

Of course here it's assumed that artifactory repo `myRepo` allows anonymous read.

Answer (score 7):

You should have a look to AQL (Artifactory Query Langage) here : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language

as an example the following AQL will retrieve all folders located in "my-repo" under "foo" folder and will display the result ordered by folder's name :

```
items.find(
    {
        "type":"folder",
        "repo":{"$eq":"my-repo"},
            "path":{"$eq":"foo"}
    }
)
.include("name")
.sort({"$desc":["name"]})
```

For cleanup you can also have a look at the following example which gives a list of the 10 biggest artifacts created more than a month ago that have never been downloaded :

```
items.find(
    {
        "type":"file",
        "repo":{"$eq":"my-repo"},
        "created":{"$before":"1mo"},
        "stat.downloads":{"$eq":null}
    }
)
.include("size","name")
.sort({"$desc":["size"]})
.limit(10)
```

Comment: I still seem to be missing some context to apply this answer. How do I execute this AQL with the command line client? The search command doesn't seem to have an option to pass AQL to it.

Comment: you can use AQL directly with the REST APi :  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL) or  within a filespec with the CLI : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-FileSpecSchemas

Comment: I'm trying the filespec option, so I do `jfrog rt search --spec=test.aql` and I put your example in the file. This doesn't work because it seems to expect JSON, not AQL like you provided. So I wrap the whole thing to put the AQL in a json attribute, and use escaping for the json-within-json, like `{ "files": [ { "aql": "items.find({\"type\":\"folder\",\"repo\":{\"$eq\":\"my-repo\"},\"path\":{\"$eq\":\"foo\"}})" }  ] }` but this results in a "failed to parse query" error.

Comment: Next I assumed that maybe the json passed to `items.find` in your example should be used directly as the value for the "aql" attribute (which seems more natural because it doesn't require escaping). Now it doesn't complain about the query, but it returns zero results...

Comment: I had another look at the documentation and figured it out finally. I posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on jroquelaure's answer, I ended up with the following. The key thing that was still missing was that you have to convert the "items.find" call into JSON when putting it in a filespec. There is an example of that in the [filespec documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-FileSpecSchemas) which I missed at first.

I put this JSON in a test.aql file:

```
{
  "files": 
    [
      {
        "aql": 
          {
            "items.find" : 
               {
                 "type":"folder",
                 "repo":{"$eq":"my-repo"},
                 "path":{"$eq":"foo"}
               }
          }
      }
    ]
}
```

Then I call `jfrog rt search --spec=test.aql`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it searches for files, if you want to list directories, add one more property `--include-dirs`

Refer the link for additional parameters. [jfrog search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles)

Here is the command.

`jf rt search --recursive=false --include-dirs=true path/`

**Response:**

```
 [
    {
        "path": "artifactory-name/path",
        "type": "folder",
        "created": "",
        "modified": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are so close, you need to include --include-dirs

`jfrog rt search --recursive=false --include-dirs my-repo/foo/* | jq '.[] | select(.type == "folder")'`

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner approach is to tell Artifactory about builds, and let it discard old ones.

There are 3 parts to this. My examples are for the jfrog command line utility:

1. When uploading files with the "**jfrog rt upload**" command, use the **--build-name *someBuildName*** and **--build-number *someBuildNumber*** arguments. This links the uploaded files to a certain build.
2. After uploading files, publish the build with "**jfrog rt build-publish *someBuildName someBuildNumber***"
3. To clean up all but the 3 latest builds, use "**jfrog rt build-discard --max-builds=3 *someBuildName***"